# Typescript : error TS1109: Expression expected

Tags: typescript, angular2-services

```
  getItems(){  
      return.this._http.get('http://localhost/api/items').map(res=>res.json());
  };
```

This error is coming in this simple code. Kindly tell me any fix of it. Thanks!

Comment: return.this. see anything wrong there? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the "." after `return`

```
getItems() {  return this._http.get('http://localhost/api/items').map(res => res.json()) };
```